# Retreive socket id from ngx-socket-io

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, socket.io, ngx-socket-io

I've recently started using **ngx-socket-io**, and i've run into some difficultys as i wanted to retreive the **socket id**. Does anyone know how this can be done ? (I'm using the service intialization not the one in the app Module)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
    
constructor(private socket: Socket) {}
    
ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.on('connect', () => console.log(this.socket.ioSocket.id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the socket instance: socket.ioSocket.id.
However you will have to wait for the socket to initialize before using it.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SocketService {
  socketId;

  constructor(private socket: Socket) {
    socket.on('connect', () => this.socketId = this.socket.ioSocket.id);
  }
}
```